# TSQL stripping number out of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string as below and assume "." always exist in the string.

**'NAB 12345 Tom Heading abcde@yahoo.com.au Web 20294821. Australia Regular Post'**

How do I strip 20294821 from the above string using TSQL?

I tried the below but it only works if the number is the last word in the string

```
REPLACE(REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(Comments), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Comments))-1 ) ) ,'.','')
```

-Alan-

Comment: Is the number to be removed always between a space and a dot?

Comment: Depending on your source data, you may have the best time just counting spaces.  Periods aren't unique, and can probably vary (email).  It's unclear if spaces in the name portion might vary (people entering an initial, or multi-part first/last names, or only one name).  How constant are other parts of your data?

Comment: @ydoow the pattern "Web xxxxxxx." always be there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can as the below:

```
DECLARE @Comments as VARCHAR(255) = 'NAB 12345 Tom Heading abcde@yahoo.com.au Web 20294821. Australia Regular Post'

SELECT REPLACE(@Comments, LEFT(RIGHT(@Comments, LEN(@Comments) - CHARINDEX('Web ', @Comments, 0) - 3), CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(@Comments, LEN(@Comments) - CHARINDEX('Web ', @Comments, 0) - 3), 0) - 1), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the possible string pattern is not certain, here I'm putting this answer based on the assumption that you want to remove the string between the rightmost dot `.` and the nearest space on the left of the `dot`.

```
DECLARE @Comments VARCHAR (MAX)
SET @Comments = 'NAB 12345 Tom Heading abcde@yahoo.com.au Web 20294821. Australia Regular Post'

DECLARE @Comments_TrimmedContent VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @Comments_TrimmedAfterDot VARCHAR (MAX) 
SELECT @Comments_TrimmedContent = REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(@Comments), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@Comments)) )) 
SELECT @Comments_TrimmedAfterDot = REVERSE( RIGHT( REVERSE(@Comments), LEN(@Comments) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@Comments)) - 1 )) 

SELECT REVERSE( RIGHT ( REVERSE(@Comments_TrimmedAfterDot), LEN(@Comments_TrimmedAfterDot) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Comments_TrimmedAfterDot)))) + @Comments_TrimmedContent
```

Output:

```
NAB 12345 Tom Heading abcde@yahoo.com.au Web. Australia Regular Post
```

Answer (score 0):

The final line has the final answer but I've broken down the steps to make things a bit more coherent.

It returns the value between the first Web space and the full stop.

```
DECLARE @Comments as VARCHAR(255)

SET @Comments = 'NAB 12345 Tom Heading abcde@yahoo.com.au Web 20294821. Australia Regular Post'

SELECT @Comments

-- Assume there is only one occurence of web and a space
SELECT CHARINDEX('Web ', @Comments)

--Show the substring starting from the number (skip for 4 characters for web and a space)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Comments, CHARINDEX('Web ', @Comments) + 4, LEN(@Comments))

--Find the full stop after the web space
SELECT CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(@Comments, CHARINDEX('Web ', @Comments) + 4, LEN(@Comments)))

--Combine all of the above logic to give the answer
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Comments, CHARINDEX('Web ', @Comments) + 4, CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(@Comments, CHARINDEX('Web ', @Comments) + 4, LEN(@Comments)))-1)
```